# NameError: undefined local variable or method `oracle' when trying to register an oracle driver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, local, undefined, nameerror

I have a Ruby class I want to talk to an oracle database and I want to use the Oracle java classes to do it.

But when I create an instance of the class below I get the error:

NameError: undefined local variable or method `oracle' for Person:Class
at the line
DriverManager.register_driver

If I comment out the lines:

```
require 'lib/ojdbc6-11.1.0.7'
DriverManager.register_driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.new
```

and uncomment the lines below (so its using the Sybase jar) I dont get this error and can connect to the database:

```
#require 'lib/jconn2'
#DriverManager.register_driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver.new
```

SAMPLE CLASS:

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/ojdbc6-11.1.0.7'
#require 'lib/jconn2'

java_import java.sql.DriverManager
java_import java.sql.SQLException

class Person

DriverManager.register_driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.new
#DriverManager.register_driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver.new

def initialize(my_id)
@my_id = my_id
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
DriverManager.registerDriver Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.new
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted it. Funny how that was not needed for the driver starting com.